# Firebase database reference or child to reference changed in Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to know what cell in a table view should be updated when a Firebase reference changes its content. My database system looks like this:

```
posts: {
   firstPostKey: {
      author: userID
      caption: "This is a post."
      replies: {
         firstReplyKey: {
            author: userID
            caption: "That's a great post!"
         }
         secondReplyKey: {
            author: userID
            caption: "It really is."
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is, that if I do something like this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in })
```

the key for the changed child would be firstPostKey, even though it was the first reply to that post, that had been edited. I want to know if it, for instance, is the caption saying "This is a post.", that has been changed, and then return firstPostKey for the key, or if it was one of the replies, and the return the key for that reply. I need to know exactly what post or reply has been edited, so I can update the corresponding cell in the table view. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey, do you really need such a fine grained change tracking capability? Why you don't just instead update the complete changed post (in your table view)?

Comment: Hi, Paulo. Maybe you are right. Posts and replies have respective cells, but maybe I could update the challenge and the corresponding replies. I'll try that. Thanks!